# Enable navigation list items to have a height of 100% of the parent flex container

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to figure out how to force my `<li>` items within my flexbox navigation bar to take up 100% of the height of the header.

The goal is to have an active class to display a blue bar when the user hovers over the item. I have mocked up my simple example here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jZzeqL

I have tried to mess with the align-items, but everything I do seems to break the center horizontal alignment.

```css
/* header styles */
.header {
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 2em;
}

#logo {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 160%;
}

#logo, nav {
  flex: 1;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  font-size: 110%;
}

nav li {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

nav li span.active {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #00A2D3; 
}

nav li > .username {
  font-weight: 400;
  padding-right: 3px;
}
```

```html
 <header class="header">
      <div id="logo">Dashboard</div>
      <nav>
        <ul role=navigation>
          <li><span class="far-li"><i class="far fa-bell"></i></span></li>
          <li><span class="fas-li"><i class="fas fa-cog"></i></span></li>
          <li><span class="username active">test-email@gmail.com</span><span class="fas-li"><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></span></li>          
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
```

Comment: Thanks for adding the code to the question. It is a **requirement** because Codepen does, on occasion, go down.

Comment: Try removing all of the default margins & Padding with a CSS reset and you're pretty much there already.